# LINQ Compare two collections on multiple properties

Tags: c#, linq

There are two collections:
`NodesWithCircuitsDown<NetworkDeviceNodeStatus>` and `RecordedImpairedNodes<NetworkDeviceNodeStatus>`.

`NetworkDeviceNodeStatus` has a `NodeId` (int) and a `CurrentStatus` (enum).

I want to create a third collection called `NodesWithDifferentImpairment`, that will contain any `NetworkDeviceNodeStatus` with a `NodeId` that's in both of the above collections, but with a `CurrentStatus` that's different.

Below is what I have so far, but I am having trouble nesting the queries to accomplish this.

```
IEnumerable<NetworkDeviceNodeStatus> NodesWithDifferentImpairment =
                NodesWithCircuitsDown.Where(x => 
                    RecordedImpairedNodes.Select(y => new { y.CurrentStatus, y.NodeId }).Select(y => y.NodeId)
            );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
NodesWithCircuitsDown.Join(RecordedImpairedNodes, 
  node => node.NodeId,
  node => node.NodeId,
  (leftNode, rightNode) => new { LeftNode = leftNode, RightNode = rightNode }).
  Where(pair => pair.LeftNode.CurrentStatus != pair.RightNode.CurrentStatus);
```

To get the pairs of nodes with different status by joining the two sets on the NodeId property, extracting the pairs and filtering those with different status.

Comment: did you mean `pair => pair.LeftNode.CurrentStatus != pair.RightNode.CurrentStatus`?

Comment: Do I also add on `.Select(pair => pair.LeftNode)` in order to get back an `IEnumerable<NetworkDeviceNodeStatus>`?  The end result should be get back the items in `NodesWithCircuitsDown` which didn't have the same CurrentStatus.

Comment: Also, note that the query syntax (as suggested by Ehsan) might be more readable in such cases (I'm just more used to the fluent syntax).

Answer (score 2):

You have to join them and then filter :

```
var NodesWithDifferentImpairment  = from nwcd in NodesWithCircuitsDown
                                    join rin in RecordedImpairedNodes on nwcd.NodId equals rin.NodeId
                                    where rin.CurrentStatus != nwcd.CurrentStatus
                                    select new  NetworkDeviceNodeStatus
                                           {
                                             CurrentStatus = rin.CurrentStatus,
                                             NodeId =  rin.NodeId

                                           };
```